# Penalty Function for XOR Gate.

Tags: optimization, constraints, quantum-computation

I have been reading a paper on [Gates for Adiabatic Quantum Computing](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1405/1405.2354.pdf).
The paper consists of penalty functions for different classical gates like AND, OR, XOR, etc.
[image]
Can someone explain how to get the penalty function for XOR Gate? I do not quite understand the process and I can not find any good resource.

Comment: Did you check reference 14 table 4.1 ?

Comment: I couldn't find that paper anywhere.